# Typescript array of 'strings array' conundrum

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array

I have some Typescript

```
let names = {};
let counts: any[] = [[] as string[]];
let c: number;
let addNames: string[] = ["a", "b", "a", "c"];
for (let i = 0; i < addNames.length; i++) {
  let n: string = addNames[i];
  if (!names[n]) {
      names[n] = 1;
      if (counts[1] === undefined) {
          counts[1] = [] as string[];
      }
      counts[1].push[n];
  } else {
      c = names[n];
      names[n]++;
      counts[c].splice(counts[c].indexOf(n), 1);
      if (counts[c + 1] === undefined) {
          counts[c + 1] = [] as string[];
      }
      counts[c + 1].push[n];
  }
}
let j = {
  names: names,
  counts: counts
}
console.log(`j: ${JSON.stringify(j)}`);
// expecting something like 
//{ names: { a: 2, b:1, c:1 }, counts: [null, ['b', 'c'], ['a']] }
```

You can try running it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20names%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20counts%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5D%20as%20string%5B%5D%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20c%3A%20number%3B%0D%0Alet%20addNames%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%2C%20%22a%22%2C%20%22c%22%5D%3B%0D%0Afor%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20addNames.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20let%20n%3A%20string%20%3D%20addNames%5Bi%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(!names%5Bn%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20names%5Bn%5D%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(counts%5B1%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20counts%5B1%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%20as%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20counts%5B1%5D.push%5Bn%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20c%20%3D%20names%5Bn%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20names%5Bn%5D%2B%2B%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20counts%5Bc%5D.splice(counts%5Bc%5D.indexOf(n)%2C%201)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(counts%5Bc%20%2B%201%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20counts%5Bc%20%2B%201%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%20as%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20counts%5Bc%20%2B%201%5D.push%5Bn%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20j%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20names%3A%20names%2C%0D%0A%20%20counts%3A%20counts%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60j%3A%20%24%7BJSON.stringify(j)%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20expecting%20something%20like%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%7B%20names%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%202%2C%20b%3A1%2C%20c%3A1%20%7D%2C%20counts%3A%20%5Bnull%2C%20%5B'b'%2C%20'c'%5D%2C%20%5B'a'%5D%5D%20%7D).

I'm expecting the answer in my comments..

But the **push** doesn't seem to be working.

I get this as a result instead:

```
j: {"names":{"a":2,"b":1,"c":1},"counts":[[],[],[]]}
```

Perhaps part of my problem is understanding the syntax for multi-dimensional array declaration.

I tried breaking it down by defining:

```
type StringArray = [string[]]
let counts:StringArray[] = [] as StringArray
```

or combinations of things like:

```
string[][]
```

or:

```
[]string[]
```

but it left me dumbfounded.

I'm wondering if someone can shed some light on this for me please.
and show me what I need to tweak to get the desired output per my comment

**{ names: { a: 2, b:1, c:1 }, counts: [null, ['b', 'c'], ['a']] }**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `[]` on the `push` function. You need to call push using `()`: `counts[1].push(n);`

Typescript does not catch this error because `push` is a `function` which in turn is an `object`, and any object has the index operator. There are valid uses for this (objects that have data but are also callable), it's just that in this case the indexing operation will return undefined.

Also might I suggest using this syntax to declare and create the array:

```
let counts: string[][] = [[]];
counts[1] = [];
```

Comment: @JGFMK Glad to help :)